# IBM Mobile First - 7.1 Installation - Facing issue at opening application center console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

Currently I'm trying to install Mobile First Server on VM and Mobile First Studio on local machine.

I started with Mobile Server Installation, For this I followed this 
[link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html). I'm facing an issue at Step 5(b) i.e Unable to open application center console. http://localhost:9080/appcenterconsole/.

> Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /appcenterconsole

Comment: Have you restarted Liberty after you did run Install Manager ? If yes, do you have an error in the Liberty log ? (usr/servers/<servername>/logs/message.log )

Comment: @DidierVidal Here is the message.log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8e0911z91azozf/messages.log?dl=0

Comment: Your Liberty server failed to open 8080 - com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPPort                       E CWWKO0221E: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint initialization did not succeed.  The socket bind did not succeed for host * and port 9080.  The port might already be in use.

Comment: So you probably have another instance of Liberty running. That's why you could not see the apps you installed.

Comment: I meant Liberty failed to open 9080.

Comment: @Didier Vidal 9080 port is free, no other application using this port number.

Comment: What happens if you stop your liberty server and go to  http://localhost:9080 ? If you see a Liberty screen it means that there is another instance of liberty running.

Comment: @Didier Vidal Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /

Comment: This error means that there is someone (Liberty) listening to that port. It's a Java exception that you have.

Comment: @VinodKumarMarupu, does this still happen after killing the Java process and start the server, or after a re-start of the host machine?

Comment: @Idan Adar, Still it is same after restarting VM.

Comment: You need to talk with whomever is controlling your VM machine. The log file clearly states that port 9080 is already taken. You need to understand what in your network setup has taken it despite thinking that nothing has taken it.

Comment: That, or use a different port in server.xml

Answer (score 1):

Despite the mentioned in the comments, the logs clearly state that the port is taken.

My suggestion is to edit the server.xml file to use different HTTP and HTTPS ports instead of the default ones.

Comment: To do this, edit server.xml and change both HTTP and HTTPS ports by replacing     <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" host="*" >




by     <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9081"
                  httpsPort="9444" host="*" >




Then restart the server and use this test URL: http://localhost:9081/appcenterconsole/.